# Notification doesn't appear in foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'm using the following code:

```
private void startForeground(boolean isActive) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getString(isActive ? R.string.title_agent_active : R.string.title_agent_inactive))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
```

and

```
 @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        startForeground(true);
        ...
```

With this code notification does not appear.

But if I replace startForeground(...) with NotificationManager.notify(...) — it shows the notification, so, I think, that at least notification building code is ok.

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using an `IntentService` the service will be destroyed as soon as `onHandleIntent()` method finishes execution and then, the notification will be removed.

Comment: The problem is that it does not appear at all :(

Comment: How long does it actually take the onHandleIntent() method to return?

Answer (score 1):

1. try to change the id into the other
2. start in `onCreate()` method
3. check the notifications are not blocked in the device
4. try to use these flags: `noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;`
5. Use usual `Service` class

try this solution (works in my app):

```
private void fg() {
        Intent intent = launchIntent(this);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);
        noti = mBuilder.build();
        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground(_.ID, noti);

    }
```